# Maven support for property substitution in /project/name?

Tags: maven, substitution

In a multi module project, I want to reuse the project name from the parent pom as part of the project name for each module. The only info I have managed to find says that property substitution is not allowed in /project/(groupId|artifactId|version), which suggests that it is allowed in /project/name.

I have tried setting /project/name to `${project.parent.name} - Some Module` in the pom for a sub module, but it seems that this property is only substituted selectively: sometimes the literal string `${project.parent.name} - Some Module` is used, sometimes the substitution works.

In the reactor summary, for example, the literal string is used:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Glorious Parent .................................... SUCCESS [  0.016 s]
[INFO] ${project.parent.name} - Some Module ............... SUCCESS [  2.482 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Same thing for the archiver when creating a manifest file using `<addDefaultSpecificationEntries>` or `<addDefaultImplementationEntries>`.

However, if I manually add manifest entries, the substitution happens:

```xml
<manifestEntries>
    <Project-Name>${project.name}</Project-Name>
</manifestEntries>
```

Results in `Project-Name: Glorious Parent - Some Module`

Is there any way to know when or where the substitution will happen, or - preferrably - to make it happen everywhere, all the time?

**Example pom.xml: (parent)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dummy-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Glorious Parent</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>child</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**Example child/pom.xml: (module)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>dummy-group-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>dummy-test-artifact</artifactId>
    <name>${project.parent.name} - Some Module</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Project-Name>${project.name}</Project-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Resulting manifest:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: ${project.parent.name} - Some Module
Project-Name: Glorious Parent - Some Module
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: developer
Specification-Title: ${project.parent.name} - Some Module
Implementation-Vendor-Id: dummy-group-id
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_31
Specification-Version: 1.0
```

**File structure:**

```
myproject/
  pom.xml
  child/
    pom.xml
```

**Maven version:** 3.2.5

Comment: Looks like a bug. Created an JIRA issue for it: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5784